# My algorithm not detect the second input as a perfect number?

Tags: c++, windows, loops, numbers

The code is supposed to detect if a number is prime / not prime, its divisors, if it's an error, and if it's a perfect number.

It detects perfect numbers in the first input; however, when another perfect number is entered by the user, it detects it as not a perfect number. Please help

```
#include < iostream >
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number{}, i=1, sum = 0;

    while ((number >= 0) && (number <= 1000)) //valid option
    {
        cout << "Enter a positive integer between 0 and 1000: ";
        cin >> number;
        cout << endl;

        if (!(cin) || (number <= 0) || (number >= 1000)) 
        {
            cout << "The number you have entered is invalid\n" << endl;

            cin.clear();        
            cin.ignore(100, '\n');

            continue;
        }

        else if (number % 2 != 0) 
        {
            cout << "The Number is Prime.\n" << endl;

        }

        else if (number % 2 == 0) 
        {
            cout << "Number is not Prime." << endl << endl;

        }
        cout << "Divisors of " << number << " are: " << endl;

        for (i = 1; i <= number; ++i)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)

                cout << i << "     ";
        }

        for (i = 1; i < number; ++i) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        if (sum == number) {
            cout << "\n\n" << number << " is a Perfect Number\n\n";

        }
        else {
            cout << "\n\n" << number << " is not a Perfect Number\n\n";

        }

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `sum` equal to 0 each time through the loop.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out!